# Maclaurin expansion of $\frac{1-y}{1-by}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

How do I expand the following expression below

$F(y)$=$\frac{1-y}{1-by}$

by Maclaurin expansion. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps the best way to go is with $1+(b-1)y\frac1{1-by}$. (And I presume you mean $F(y)$).

Comment: Very similar to your previous question less than an hour ago (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2492723) **with no more efforts**. Don't use this site for having solutions served on a tray. This is not the way you will progress in mathematics.

Comment: Also a score of 1 for 6 month presence and no question older than a day, mean this post is likely to be self-deleted and a waste of time for posters...

Comment: Now he shouldn't be able to self-delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Write the term as $$\frac{1}{b}-\frac{1-b}{b}\frac{1}{ 1-b y}$$
recall the sum of geometric series
$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } (b y)^n=\frac{1}{ 1-b y}$$
so the original function can be written as
$$\frac{1-y}{1-by}=\frac{1}{b}-\frac{1-b}{b}\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } (b y)^n$$

Answer (score 0):

Use $\frac1{1-x}=1+x+x^2+\dots$
$$\frac1{1-by}=1+by+b^2y^2+\dots$$
$$\frac{1-y}{1-by}=1+by+b^2y^2+\dots-y-by^2-\dots$$

$$=1+(b-1)y+b(b-1)y^2+b^2(b-1)y^3+\dots$$

Comment: See my comment : this OP doesn't work by (him/her)self. It's up to you to give "ready for use" proofs, but....

Comment: @JeanMarie ...and changes account every moment... :) And if gives no points I'll not answer to his/her questions any more